# How To Send Vault logs to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, hashicorp-vault, cloudwatch-alarms

When running Hashicorp Vault on EC2, I'm able to install the CloudWatch agent and ship logs to over CloudWatch in order to create alerts and notifications on specific events.

However, when running Vault via a helm chart in Kubernetes, I'm not sure how to go about the same thing.

Is there a way to install the CloudWatch agent when running Vault in Kubernetes? Or some other way to get the logs to CloudWatch?

I have the file audit device enabled at vault/audit/vault_audit.log but all the logs are currently sitting on that file.

It's back by persistent storage, but ideally, ,I'd like to get it into CloudWatch somehow.